# How to use pyodbc library in a Google Cloud Function?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, pyodbc

I am trying to implement a Google Cloud Function with Python 3.8 Beta as runtime while using the `pyodbc` module. I am getting an error while trying to implement it.

As far as I understand by reading other Stack Overflow questions, to use `pyodbc` on a linux distribution you need to sudo install some things before you can use `pyodbc` as it needs some OS specific resources.

Does anyone has an idea how to do this or knows another way to make `pyodbc` work in a Google Cloud Function?

The implementation error google cloud functions is throwing:

```
Build failed: ...: sql.h: No such file or directory
#include <sql.h>
^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyodbc
Building wheel for pyodbc (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
Running setup.py clean for pyodbc
Successfully built ftputil
Failed to build pyodbc
Installing collected packages: pytz, six, python-dateutil, numpy, pandas, ftputil, pyodbc, setuptools, zope.interface, datetime
Running setup.py install for pyodbc: started
Running setup.py install for pyodbc: finished with status 'error'
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: /opt/python3.8/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-np63kzip/pyodbc/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-np63kzip/pyodbc/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-2ijqo8fi/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --home /tmp/pip-target-3prwz462 --compile --install-headers /tmp/pip-target-3prwz462/include/python/pyodbc
cwd: /tmp/pip-install-np63kzip/pyodbc/
Complete output (14 lines):
running install
running build
running build_ext
building 'pyodbc' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fstack-protector-strong -g -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -DPYODBC_VERSION=4.0.30 -I/opt/python3.8/include/python3.8 -c src/buffer.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/buffer.o -Wno-write-strings
In file included from src/buffer.cpp:12:0:
src/pyodbc.h:56:10: fatal error: sql.h: No such file or directory
#include <sql.h>
^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible. The `pyodbc` project [requires the `unixobdc-dev` platform package](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/441#issuecomment-413167355), which is not in the [list of system packages included in the Cloud Functions runtime](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/python-system-packages).

Instead, you may want to use [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/) which allows you to define your own runtime and install any platform packages that you want.

Comment: Any feasiblity now in cloud function to use `pyodbc`? Above question was answered 3 years before. I hope there should be an option by now.